# Loop over files in Twig

Tags: twig, bolt-cms, file-listing

I am using Bolt CMS and want to have a table including all files of a specific directory on the server. How can this be achieved using a Twig template?

Comment: can you give more details, e.g. what you've tried so far, what your output would look like etc

Comment: There are audio files in that directory and I want to create links to them, so visitors can listen to the files I think the parsing is no problem, I just need to know how it works. I need something like this: `<a href="{FileNameHere}">PartOfFileNameHere</a>`. Actually the only thing I found on the net was on the Twig homepage stating there is a `Twig_Loader_Filesystem` class. But I'm new to twig and `{{ fs = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/files') }}` or `{{ set fs = Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/files') }}` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the following call works. The argument is a path in the files directory.

{% set files = app.filesystem.browse('SomeDirectory')[0] %}

Comment: This actually works quite well for me and now I can finally abandon the custom extension. I only struggled a bit, as the root directory was under "/files" and not "/". But that also worked out well. Thanks for this!

Comment: Update: In Bolt 3 the interface slightly changed, now you need to use `{% set files = app.filesystem.listContents('files://SomeDirectory') %}`

Answer (score 0):

This is not twig's task. This is something the controller layer should be responsible.

Get the list of files in your controller (though I'd probably create a model-layer class for this), and pass the list to your view, where it only needs to display it.

Comment: And the "controller level" in Bolt-CMS is Symphony, right? How can I extend this? Do you have an example or a link to the documentation? Sorry, I'm really new with Bolt and only have performed some very basic tasks.

Comment: The site says silex, so yeah, effectively symfony. Never used bolt so cannot help, sorry.

Comment: I solved this by creating a little bolt extension which returns a list of files from a directory. Like that I only need to create links from the file list in Twig.